# Why is my listview not returning me to my DetailActivity.class when I'm clicking an item on my Listview?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having trouble with my ListView. It always sends me back to my login page whenever I press an item on the list. It supposed to go to the details page.

### HomeActivity

```
package com.example.kun.carcarkila;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.amigold.fundapter.BindDictionary;
import com.amigold.fundapter.FunDapter;
import com.amigold.fundapter.extractors.StringExtractor;
import com.amigold.fundapter.interfaces.DynamicImageLoader;
import com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
final String LOG = "HomeActivity";

private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private ListView lvProduct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(HomeActivity.this)); // Do it on Application start

    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(HomeActivity.this, this);
    taskRead.execute("http://10.0.2.2/carkila/product.php");


}

@Override
public void processFinish(String s) {

            productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);

    BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();

    dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return item.img;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarModel, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return "Car Model: " + item.Car_Model;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarType, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return "Car Type: " +  item.Car_Type;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCapacity, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return "Capacity: " + item.Capacity;
        }
    });

    FunDapter<Product> adapter = new FunDapter<>(
            HomeActivity.this, productList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);
    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Product selectedProduct = productList.get(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("product", (Serializable) selectedProduct);
    startActivity(in);
}
}
```

I learned this code on a youtube channel and I know i followed the instructions well and I'm always checking the intent and still the problem is there. Thank you Guys in advance. :)

This is my DetailActivity.class. Does this have my problem?

### DetailActivity

```
package com.example.kun.carcarkila;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvCarModel, tvCarType, tvCapacity;
ImageView ivImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(DetailActivity.this));

    Product product = (Product) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("product");

    tvCarModel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarModel);
    tvCarType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarType);
    tvCapacity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCapacity);
    ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

    if(product != null){
        tvCarModel.setText(product.Car_Model);
        tvCarType.setText(product.Car_Type);
        tvCapacity.setText(product.Capacity);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(product.img, ivImage);
    }
}

}
```

### Debug

```
in = {Intent@830622078952} "Intent { cmp=com.example.kun.carcarkila/.DetailActivity }"
mAction = null
mCategories = null
mClipData = null
mComponent = {ComponentName@830622081720} "ComponentInfo{com.example.kun.carcarkila/com.example.kun.carcarkila.DetailActivity}"
mData = null
mExtras = null
mType = null
mPackage = null
mSelector = null
mSourceBounds = null
mFlags = 0
```

### Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.kun.carcarkila">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="@android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.kun.carcarkila.HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

### Product Class

```
package com.example.kun.carcarkila;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Product {

@SerializedName("Car_No")
public int Car_No;
@SerializedName("Car_Model")
public String Car_Model;
@SerializedName("Car_Type")
public String Car_Type;
@SerializedName("Capacity")
public int Capacity;
@SerializedName("img")
public String img;
}
```

Comment: do one thing use try catch for getting data from intent in details activity, as I think there is problem in getting data and there fore it is redirecting you in main activity so use try catch and check

Comment: Where should i put my try catch? Can you demonstrate. I'm a beginner. Thanks. @Vickyexpert

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for detail activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tvCarModel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarModel);
        tvCarType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarType);
        tvCapacity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCapacity);
        ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(DetailActivity.this));

        try {
              Product product = (Product) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("product");

               if(product != null)
               {
                    tvCarModel.setText(product.Car_Model);
                    tvCarType.setText(product.Car_Type);
                    tvCapacity.setText(product.Capacity);
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(product.img, ivImage);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in details " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `07-08 17:53:11.935 8490-8490/com.example.kun.carcarkila I/System.out: Error in detailsjava.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kun.carcarkila.Product cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable`  @Vickyexpert

Comment: I put it on my HomeActivity where i made my intent. @Vickyexpert

Comment: There's my product class now. I want to thank you in advance sir! :D @Vickyexpert

Comment: Ok you need to declare your class as below

Comment: Public class Product implements Serializable